# how to get key window reference of active application on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos

I'm writing a service application runs in the background, and captures the "focus" window on Mac OS X. "focus" window means the window is currently receiving user input. (in Mac I think this is called `key window`)
I'm currently using `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);` to get the list of the windows, and get the first window whose `kCGWindowLayer == 0`. (as the list is in order of front to back).

But this is not always the case. Sometimes if an active application pops up a modeless dialog, the modeless dialog will become the key window, but it is not the first window with `kCGWindowLayer == 0`, so I'll get a wrong window.

What is the correct method to get the key window of the active application? Or an notification callback that can tell me the change of the key window is also OK.

Also, as I'm operating on a window not belong to my application, NSApplication.windowWithWindowNumber may not work.